# Переименование вкладки "Действия" в профиле

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено

Вкладку "Действия" нужно переименовать на "Активность", так как **никаких действий** над профилем там **не производится**, а просматривается только активность профиля.

[image]

Comment: Угу, поддерживаю.